# Filtering array using service in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm just trying to display the current items (not the new added ones) of an array based on property of object. The array goes from a service to a component. I tried different methods that work isolated from angular but when I try them in the angular lifecycle maze it doesn't work.

This is the service:

```
  private transactions: Transaction [] = [
    new Transaction('Coles', 27.8, 'Groceries'),
    new Transaction('Translink', 20, 'Transportation'),
  ];


  getTransaction()  {
    return this.transactions.slice();
  }

  getGroceries(transactions: Transaction)  {
     for (item of this.transactions) {
       if (item.category === "groceries")
         this.groceries.push(item);
}
    }
```

This is the component:

```
export class TransactionsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  transactions: Transaction[];
  groceriesList: Transaction[]; 
  private igChangeSub: Subscription

  constructor(private trService:TransactionsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.transactions = this.trService.getTransaction();
    this.igChangeSub = this.trService.transactionsChanged
      .subscribe(
        (transactions: Transaction[]) => {
          this.transactions = transactions; 
        }
      )   
      this.groceriesList = this.trService.getGroceries(transactions: Transaction[])  
    }


   onAddItem(form: NgForm) {
    const value = form.value;
    const newTransaction = new Transaction(value.name, value.amount, value.category)
    this.trService.addTransaction(newTransaction)
  }

  ngOnDestroy (): void {
    this.igChangeSub.unsubscribe();
  }


}
```

I've also tried

```
getGroceries() {
    for(let item of this.transactions) {
      let groceries = this.transactions.filter( a=>a.category === "Groceries")
      console.log(groceries)

   }
  }
```

I was unsure if I had to create the new array on the service or on the component (none worked). Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Here's the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6ni1pg

Comment: So you're basically trying to create a service that manages your array and allow external components to update the array?

Comment: That's the next step. i'm just trying to display the array based on the category at the moment.

Comment: Do you have a stackblitz?

Comment: No, I'm trying to create one now but it's not working

Comment: I created one for you. It's mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of using an angular service for state. The thing to remember is that you want to stick to the rule of keeping all updates to your transactions 'fake database' (or whatever you want to call it) in a central location (the service)

here is a Stackblitz demonstrating it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hkbkmy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

There are multiple other ways to accomplish this by using `EventEmitters`, `Subjects`, `Observables`, etc... However, if you find yourself wanting a good tool to manage state, I would suggest looking into [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/) However, I will say that if you find yourself struggling with understanding the Angular Lifecycle Hooks and the general flow of angular, taking on a State Machine like NgRx might be a little much right now. But, it's certainly the go-to for state management in angular

**Service**

```
export class TransactionServiceService {
  private transactions: Transaction[];
  constructor() {
    this.transactions = [];
  }
  addTransaction(transaction: Transaction): Transaction[] {
    this.transactions.push(transaction);
    return this.transactions;
  }
  removeTransaction(transaction: Transaction): Transaction[] {
    return this.transactions.filter(t =>
      t.name !== transaction.name &&
      t.amount !== transaction.amount &&
      t.category !== transaction.category
    );
  }
  getTransactions(): Transaction[] {
    return this.transactions;
  }
  getTransactionsByCategory(category: string): Transaction[] {
    return this.transactions.filter( t => t.category === category);
  }
}
```

Afer you've built your CRUD functions within your service to manage the Transactions state, you can then use it in any component:

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TransactionServiceService } from './transaction-service.service';
import { Transaction } from './transaction';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  private readonly transactionService: TransactionServiceService;
  public transactions: Transaction[];
  constructor(transactionService: TransactionServiceService) {
    this.transactionService = transactionService;
    const transactions = [
      { name: 'Coles', amount: 27.8, category: 'Groceries' } as Transaction,
      { name: 'TransLink', amount: 20, category: 'Transportation' } as Transaction,
      { name: 'TransLink', amount: 25, category: 'Transportation' } as Transaction
    ];
    transactions.forEach(t => this.transactionService.addTransaction(t) );
  }
  getItems(): void {
    this.transactions = this.transactionService.getTransactions();
  }
  filterTransactions(category: string): void {
    this.transactions = this.transactionService.getTransactionsByCategory(category);
  }
}
```

**Template**

```
<button (click)="getItems()">Get All Items</button>
<button (click)="filterTransactions('Groceries')">Get Groceries</button>
<button (click)="filterTransactions('Transportation')">Get Transportation</button>
<div *ngFor="let transaction of transactions">{{transaction | json}}</div>
```

If you're trying to get the last transaction, you can easily get it since this method uses `Array.push`. However, I would recommend adding an identifier to your transactions so it's easier to locate them.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I'm trying to understand your code (I've been learning angular only for 1 month). Why aren't you using ngOnInit in the component?

Comment: Ok now I was able to put together a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6ni1pg

Comment: You could move the constructor logic to `ngOnInit`, but it's not necessary. I try and avoid importing anything that I don't absolutely need. If I wanted to use `ngOnInit`, I would need to import `OnInit` from core. Although `ngOnInit` is present when you generate a component, it doesn't mean you need it.

Answer (score 1):

First I would recommend you to use interface instead of classes for Transaction. Reason being that they are easier to work with. You don't have to new them up, and you can work with them a little more loosely. It is a matter of taste I suppose, but at work we have sort of a rule that we only use classes if you want them to do something. Data models we want as interfaces.

Anyway, that's not really what you want to know. The problem here is that your transactions probably don't get a new reference. Angular changedetection doesn't pick up that you have changed the array and doesn't redraw that part. I assume that you checked during debugging that the data is what you expect them to be?

If so, it should just be a matter of doing this:

```
this.igChangeSub = this.trService.transactionsChanged
      .subscribe(
        (transactions: Transaction[]) => {
          this.transactions = [...transactions]; 
        }
      )   
      this.groceriesList = this.trService.getGroceries(transactions: Transaction[])  
    }
```

or this:

```
  onAddItem(form: NgForm) {
    const value = form.value;
    const newTransaction = new Transaction(value.name, value.amount, value.category)
    this.trService.addTransaction(newTransaction)
    this.transactions = [...this.trService.getTransaction()]
  }
```

This should create a new array, which is a new reference and then this.transactions should get a new reference that will trigger change detection.

You didn't post everything, so it could be something that I'm missing. I don't know how you have hooked up your trService.addTransaction with the subscription, so there could possibly be something wrong there too.

Comment: Just to clarify, all I'm trying is to display the groceries (in the component) items based on the current array (in the service). So I'm not trying to use "onAddItem()" yet.

Comment: Finally I can comment. I think mWilson has the most elaborate answer here and gave you a good foundation for fixing this.